# shadow around the text box

Tags: html, css

I am very new to CSS. I am told to create the text box just like so:

[image]

My supervisor wants the shadow around the box when clicked and then same kind of text box. How can I achieve this.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo selector to style an element when it is on focus

```css
.input-field:focus{
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px  rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<input class="input-field" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `<input>` HTML element to create your text box.

```
<input type="text" name="Business Name">
```

The browser should automatically create that type of shadow with the highlight colour set in the computer.

The `input` element has so many attributes and input types that I won't list them here, but I recommend checking out the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input.

If you want to put "Business Name" above your text box, it's best practice to use a `label`:

```
<label for="business-name">Business Name</label>
<input type="text" id="business-name">
```

Make sure that the id matches for both tags so that they reference one another.

Answer (score 3):

You would usually use a `:focus` pseudo-class and `box-shadow` attribute to achieve something like this. In your case, CSS would look roughly like this

```css
input:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px #acdfea;
    }
```

```html
<input class="input" />
```

Modify the values for color and the spread of the shadow as needed.

Read up more on the `:focus` pseudo-class here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus